# Can't write text sent by javascript to a .txt file using python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I'm having an error, while tring to write my string variable sent from javascript to a .txt file in cgi. this is the python cgi code with the error:

```
          1  #!/usr/bin/python
          2
          3 import cgi, cgitb
          4 cgitb.enable()
          5
          6 print "Content-type: text/html"
          7 print
          8
          9 print "<html><head><title>Nimed</title></head><br/>"
         10  
         12 formdata = cgi.FieldStorage()
         13 tulemused = formdata.getvalue('tulemused')
         14 f = open('/home/t103692/public_html/prax3/tulemused.txt', 'a')
    =>   15 f.write(tulemused)
         16 f.close()
    f = <open file '/home/t103692/public_html/prax3/tulemused.txt', mode 'a'>, f.write =      <built-in method write of file object>, tulemused = None

    <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected a character buffer object 
          args = ('expected a character buffer object',) 
          message = 'expected a character buffer object'
```

And here's the javascript code, where I send the variable:

```
    function saadaTulemused() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://dijkstra.cs.ttu.ee/~t103692/cgi-bin/save.py", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(tulemused);
    }
```

"tulemused" is the string variable, which already contains some text without spaces.

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tulemused` is `None` and you cannot write that to a file.

You need to actually send `x-www-form-urlencoded` data from your JavaScript handler; currently you only send the value and nothing else.

Prefixing the string with `'tulemused='` should be enough:

```
xmlhttp.send("tulemused=" + tulemused);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Finally got it to work, been trying to figure it out for days.